How to Filter Values in an Array Using ADF Data Flow
I have multiple JSON files and need assistance with filtering values in the array distributionReason[ ]. I'm unsure if my data flow configuration is correct. I have encountered issues with the filter and sink(entire record). see screenshots for reference.
Here is an example JSON file:
{
  "record": {
     "ns": "meta",
     "type": "SW",
       "metadata": {
          "markings": {
             "ns": "meta",
             "redactableData": {
                "ns": "meta",
                "distributionReasons": {
                    "ns": "meta",
                    "distributionReason": [
                         {
                           "num": "1",
                           "ns": "meta",
                           "code": "SW",
                           "description": "SW value"
                         }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
}

my expect output if there is a match the code in the array distributionReason[] then entire root record json above copy to sink.
Data Flow Setup:
Source:

Derived Column 1:
I tried to derive distributionReasons to use the flatten transformation.
•   record: 'record'
•   distributionReasons: 'record.metadata.markings.redactableData.distributionReasons'

Flatten 1:
Unroll by: 'record.metadata.markings.redactable.distributionReasons'

Filter:
distributionReasons.distributionReason.code == 'SW'
I also try contains(distributionReasons.distributionReason.code,#item == 'SW')
Error: It doesn't work because it is an array. I don't know how to filter when it involves an array.

Sink:
I want to copy the entire root record to the sink if there is a match in the filter transformation.
Input Columns: Why don't I see the root 'record' node?


So, Is JSON structure same for all files? and can you provide your expected output for the above JSON?

Not all files have the same json structure, some files are missing element distributionReason[ ].  The output is entire json record for above json.

Are the distributionReason array records should be filtered by comparing the code with value SW? or the JSON files which contains at least one code of distributionReason array equals to SW should be filtered? So, can you provide your expected output for the above JSON? I mean can you explain the filter condition?

filter by comparing the code with value SW, TH, or PH.   The output if there is a match code in the array distributionReason[ ] then entire json (everything in the file) above copy to sink.

Are you passing all JSON files one by one in a loop to the dataflow and copying to its sink? or using any wildcard path to merge all records from the source JSON files and copying all files records to a single file in one go?

passing all JSON files one by one in a loop to the dataflow, then searching for code with value SW,TH, or PH for each file.  If there is a match, then transfer the entire json file to sink.

Ok, let me try from my end.


Are you passing all JSON files one by one in a loop to the dataflow and copying to its sink? or using any wildcard path to merge all records from the source JSON files and copying all files records to a single file in one go?

Either way, the below approach will work to achieve your requirement.
As checking is only for 3 values, you can directly use filter transformation with below expression after the source.
notEquals(instr(replace(toString(byName('record')),' ',''),'"distributionReason":[{'),0) && 
(notEquals(instr(replace(toString(byPath('record.metadata.markings.redactableData.distributionReasons.distributionReason')),' ',''),'"code":"SW"'),0) || 
notEquals(instr(replace(toString(byPath('record.metadata.markings.redactableData.distributionReasons.distributionReason')),' ',''),'"code":"TH"'),0) || 
notEquals(instr(replace(toString(byPath('record.metadata.markings.redactableData.distributionReasons.distributionReason')),' ',''),'"code":"PH"'),0))


The above condition will work like <cond1> && (<cond2> || <cond3> || <cond4>). In this, the cond1,cond2 and cond3 will get evaluated only when the cond1 is true. If its false, then the expression result will be false.
Similarly, the above expression first checks whether the JSON contains the distributionReason array element or not. If it does not contain the required element, then the filter expression will result to false and the JSON won't be filtered. If it does contain, then it will check(or()) for the required values by converting the record object into a JSON string.
Result:

Add your sink dataset after the filter and the required JSON will be copied to your sink.
But you need to note that if there is no distributionReason array element in the file or if the file does not meet the required conditions (containing required values), both will give an empty JSON file with given name in the sink dataset. If there is an existing file in the sink location, this will overwrite that file and make it as an empty file.
